# Spatial search with ravenDB

Tags: solr, lucene.net, ravendb

I have a rather specific spatial search I need to do.  Basically, have an object (lets call it obj1) with two locations, lets call them point A and point B.

I then have a collection of objects(lets call each one obj2) each with their own A and B locations.

I want to return the top 10 objects from the collection sorted by:

(distance from obj1 A to obj2A) + (the distance from obj1B to obj2B)

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Nick

Update:
Here's a little more detail on the documents and how I want to compare them.

The domain model:

Listing:
ListingId int
Title string
Price double
Origin Location
Destination Location

Location:
Post / Zipcode string
Latitude decimal
Longitude decimal

What i want to do is take a listing object (not in the database) and compare it with the collection of listings in the database.  I want the query to return the top 12 (or x) number of listings sorted by the crow flies distance from the origins plus the crow flies distance from destinations.

I don't care about the distance from origin to destination - only about the distance of origin to origin plus destination to destination.

Basically Im trying to find listings where the starting and ending locations are close.

Please let me know if I can clarify more.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post details about how you want to measure distance? Many of the spatial search methods rely on the distance measure being used satisfying a few key properties. The distance function d needs to satisfy that d(x,y)=0 if and only if x=y, d(x,y)=d(y,x) and something known as the triangle inequality. Given 3 points x,y,z then d(x,y)+d(y,z) >=d(x,z)

Comment: Can you post an example of your documents and the result you want to see?  From the looks of it, you want to compare every object against every other object, twice, for distance?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you find a solution directly out of the box.

It'll be much more efficient if you use a bounding sphere instead of a bounding box to specify your object. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere

```
     C = ( A + B)/2 and R = distance(A,B) /2
```

You do not precise how much data you want to compare. And if you want to see the closests or the farthest objects pair.

For both case, I think that you have to encode C coordinate as a path in an octtree if you are using 3D or quadtree if you are using 2D.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

This is a first draft I can add more information if this not enough.
If you are not familiar with 3D start with 2D it easier to start with.

I show your latest add, it seems that your problem is very similar to clash detection algorithm.

I think that if you change the coordinate system of the "end-point" by polar coordinate relative to the "start-point". If you round the radial coordinate to your tolerance (x miles), and order them by this value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one would solve such a problem in

[mysql 4.1](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html) &

[mysql 5](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/GIS_Functions#Introduction).

The link from mysql 4.1 seems quite helpful, esp. the first example, it's pretty much what you are asking about.

But if this is not quite helpful, I guess you'd have to loop and do queries either on obj1 or obj2 against its counterpart table.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but i do know how to do it in a relational DB

Comment: If you`re using db as well as solr, then on index time of say OBJ1 table, run the query as found in the article in example one and modify the schema to store what is it`s closest counterpart in OBJ2 table.  I wouldn`t know how to do it in ravenDB.  If you cannot do so in mysql or postgis, then write a script to loop query each row in OBJ1 against OBJ2 already indexed in (solr) & I guess you`d create another index have store the result of these queries which acts as the closest distance bet OBJ1 & OBJ2.

Answer (score 0):

From algorithmic perspective, I'd find the center of the bounding box, then picked candidates with increasing radius while I find enough.

Also I just want to remind that crow fly distance over the globe is not Pythagoras distance and different formula must be used:

```
public static double GetDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
{
    double deltaLat = DegreesToRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double deltaLong = DegreesToRadians(lng2 - lng1);

    double a = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) +
        Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(lat1))
        * Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(lat2))
        * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(deltaLong / 2), 2);

    return earthMeanRadiusMiles * (2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're building a rideshare website. :)

The bottom line is that in order to sort your query result by surface distance, you'll need spatial indexing built into the database engine.  I think your options here are MySQL with OpenGIS extensions (already mentioned) or [PostgreSQL with PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/).  It looks like it's possible in ravenDB too: http://ravendb.net/documentation/indexes/sptial

But if that's not an option, there's a few other ways. Let's simplify the problem and say you just want to sort your database records by their distance to location A, since you're just doing that twice and summing the result.

The simplest solution is to pull every record from the database and calculate the distance to location A one by one, then sort, in code.  Trouble is, you end up doing a lot of redundant computations and pulling down the entire table for every query.

Let's once again simplify and pretend we only care about the [Chebyshev (maximum) distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance). This will work for narrowing our scope within the db before we get more accurate.  We can do a "binary search" for nearby records.  We must decide an approximate number of closest records to return; let's say **10**.  Then we query inside of a square area, let's say 1 degree latitude by 1 degree longitude (that's about 60x60 miles) around the location of interest. Let's say our location of interest is lat,lng=43.5,86.5.  Then our db query is SELECT COUNT(*) FROM locations WHERE (lat > 43 AND lat < 44) AND (lng > 86 AND lng < 87). If you have indexes on the lat/lng fields, that should be a fast query.

Our goal is to get just above **10** total results inside the box. Here's where the "binary search" comes in. If we only got 5 results, we double the box area and search again.  If we got 100 results, we cut the area in half and search again. If we get 3 results immediately after that, we increase the box area by 50% (instead of 100%) and try again, proceeding until we get close enough to our 10 result target.

Finally we take this manageable set of records and calculate their euclidean distance from the location of interest, and sort, in code.

Good luck!

Comment: The end of your algorithm have some quadtree flavour isn't it ?

Comment: Tried building a solution based on the first part of Matt's answer, but for some reason it's failing to return the results I'd expect. (Expanding the search radius returns less. So I've got an operator messed up somewhere and can't see it)